how to handle vue 3 dynamic breadcrumbs in Quasar Project
This is my breadcrumbs component
<template>
  <q-breadcrumbs class="text-black" active-color="grey">
    <q-breadcrumbs-el
      v-for="crumb in breadcrumbs"
      :key="crumb.path"
      :to="crumb.path"
    >
      <span class="g-text-h4">
        {{ crumb.label }}
      </span>
    </q-breadcrumbs-el>
    <template #separator>
      <q-icon size="md" name="sym_o_chevron_right" />
    </template>
  </q-breadcrumbs>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from 'vue';
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const route = useRoute();
const { t } = useI18n();

const breadcrumbs = computed(() => {
  const paths = route.path.split('/').filter(Boolean);

  return paths.map((path, index) => {
    const currentRoute = route.matched[index + 1];
    const staticLabel = currentRoute?.meta?.breadcrumb as string;

    // If static breadcrumb is defined in route meta, use it
    if (staticLabel) {
      return {
        label: t(staticLabel),
        path: '/' + paths.slice(0, index + 1).join('/'),
      };
    }

    // Otherwise, try to get dynamic label from entity details
    const label = decodeURIComponent(path);

    return {
      label,
      path: '/' + paths.slice(0, index + 1).join('/'),
    };
  });
});
</script>

I want to make breadcrumbs dynamic and also have the static breadcrumbs
this is my frameworks routes which I want to handle both static and dynamic breadcrumbs
import { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';

const frameworksRoutes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: 'frameworks',
    component: () => import('../layout/FrameworksMainLayout.vue'),
    meta: {
      breadcrumb: 'global.navigation.frameworks',
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: () => import('../pages/FrameworksMainPage.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: ':frameworkId',
        component: () => import('../pages/FrameworkDetailsPage.vue'),
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: () => import('../components/CompetenciesEmptyPanel.vue'),
          },
          {
            path: ':roleId',
            component: () => import('../components/CompetenciesPanel.vue'),
          },
          {
            path: ':roleId/:competencyId',
            component: () => import('../components/TKSPanel.vue'),
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default frameworksRoutes;

the part with meta.breadcrumbs handle static values
but with dynamic values I only got here is the id of the entity
I got something like
frameworks > 2 > 4 > 3
however, I want the name of the entity like this
Frameworks > NICE v1 > Communication Security > Competency 1
this is the part where I navigate to framework details from frameworks list, and it handled the same for all levels of framework
function handleFrameworkNavigate(frameworkDetails: IFramework) {
  redirectTo(`/frameworks/${frameworkDetails.id}/`);
}


Where does "Communication Security" come from? If data for a route that contains it has been fetched, you need to resolve id to it similarly to how you would do for e.g. page header
